# How to get Taylor Series of $\sin \frac{x}{1-x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I know that $\displaystyle\sin x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^kx^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$

But how to get transformation to get Series about x?

Comment: substitute $x=\frac{m}{1-m}$  into the series. That's all you need to do!

Comment: That is "all" you need to do, you say.  Indeed, you can get as many terms as you like that way.  But can you get a closed form for the terms?

Answer (score 0):

**comment**
From Maple, I get
$$\sin\frac{x}{1-x} =
x+{x}^{2}+{\frac {5}{6}}{x}^{3}+{\frac {1}{2}}{x}^{4}+{\frac {1}{120}
}{x}^{5}-{\frac {5}{8}}{x}^{6}-{\frac {6931}{5040}}{x}^{7}-{\frac {
1591}{720}}{x}^{8}-{\frac {224179}{72576}}{x}^{9}-{\frac {31987}{8064}
}{x}^{10}-{\frac {27323293}{5702400}}{x}^{11}-{\frac {19986991}{
3628800}}{x}^{12}-{\frac {1508675351}{249080832}}{x}^{13}-{\frac {
3055361231}{479001600}}{x}^{14}-{\frac {8385570334051}{1307674368000}}
{x}^{15}-{\frac {16115825351}{2641766400}}{x}^{16}-{\frac {
1916072623603199}{355687428096000}}{x}^{17}-{\frac {88344037902079}{
20922789888000}}{x}^{18}-{\frac {12475149135090259}{4865804016353280}}
{x}^{19}+O \left( {x}^{20} \right)
$$
So, can we "recognize" these terms to guess a formula?  Can we even say that all subsequent coefficients are negative?